# Stack equivalent to SOS !DumpHeap command

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

I'm looking for a commant like `!DumpHeap` in SOS Debugging Tool, but for the stack.

Is there any command like this in SOS? In other debugging tools?
Is it even possible? If not, why?

Thanks

Comment: A more general comment - `!sos.help` will list `!sos.dumpheap`, `!sos.clrstack`, and many other commands. This built-in help is a lot more detailed than MSDN; unfortunately, it is only available in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is !clrstack.  Reference [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx).

Comment: Just adding: Remember to switch to the relevant thread or use `~*e!clrstack` to list managed stacks for all threads.